# Temporarily undefining a "starred" command

Tags: macros, amsmath, starred-version

I would like to temporarily undefine a command. The reason for this is that I need to use a specific class file which defines the equation* using \@namedef and I would also really like to use the amsmath package as it in particular defines the align environment, but it also defines the equation* environment, so this leads to an error at compilation.

I have found how to temporarily disable a command without a star, i.e. by doing

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldequation\equation
\let\equation\@undefined
\makeatother
```

and then loading the amsmath package.

This doesn't work for equation* for reasons I don't quite understand, but apparently * at the end starts a new lexeme.

So how would I achieve a similar result for equation*? The class and style files are not under my control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as `\makeatletter` locally makes `@` a letter you can locally make `*` a letter.

```
\catcode`\*=11
\makeatletter
\let\oldequation*\equation*
\let\equation*\@undefined
\let\oldendequation*\endequation*
\let\endequation*\@undefined
\makeatother
\catcode`\*=12
```